# Socket IO in React Native firing multiple events

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I have been reading similar topics but I did not really get the their solutions. I have read that the cause of this behavior is if you are re-registering a new event handler. In my code I am not sure which part I am re-registering a new event handler.

SERVER

```
socket.on('test', function (data) {
  socket.emit('test2', data);
});
```

CLIENT

```
  save() {
    app.io.emit('test', { hello: 'world' });
    app.io.on('test2', (res)=>{
      if(Object.keys(res).length > 0) {
        console.log(res);
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title='Save' onPress={this.save}></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

The problem here is this, when I click the button SAVE, the number of return that the function `app.io.on` is throwing keeps bumping up.

Ex:

First click return once
Second click return twice
Third click returns 3x

Is there a way to prevent this from happening like it should only return once? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyways, I sorted it out by moving the code

```
app.io.on('test2', (res)=>{
  if(Object.keys(res).length > 0) {
    console.log(res);
  }
})
```

on the componentDidMount() so it will called once. The event will keep on bumping up (firing multiple times) everytime this function is called which is the caused of my problem.